# Como receber mais de um comando do usuário de uma só vez?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por Exemplo:

```
nasc= input('INFORME SUA DATA DE NASCIMENTO: ')
RESPOSTA= 15112002
```

Como separar isso em DIA/MÊS/ANO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal:

```
from datetime import datetime

nasc = input("Informe sua data de nascimento: ")

try:
    obj = datetime.strptime( nasc, '%d%m%Y')
except ValueError:
    obj = None

if obj:
    print("Data Completa: %s" % (obj.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')))
    print("Dia: %s" % (obj.strftime('%d')))
    print("Mes: %s" % (obj.strftime('%m')))
    print("Ano: %s" % (obj.strftime('%Y')))
else:
    print("Data de nascimento invalida!")
```

Teste #1:

```
Informe sua data de nascimento: 15112002
Data Completa: 15/11/2002
Dia: 15
Mes: 11
Ano: 2002
```

Teste #2:

```
Informe sua data de nascimento: 12345678
Data de nascimento invalida!
```

Teste #3:

```
Informe sua data de nascimento: 29021017
Data de nascimento invalida!
```

Answer (score 1):

As formas mais **simples** de se fazer isso são as seguintes:

`nasc` é uma string, as strings são listas de caracteres. Então você pode dividir ela em dia, mes e ano.

```
nasc= input('INFORME SUA DATA DE NASCIMENTO: ')
dia = nasc[0:2]
mes = nasc[2:4]
ano = nasc[4:8]
```

Ou você pode usar um metodo que tem nas proprias strings que é o split() que retorna uma lista de string, ai seu usuario precisa digitar com algum caractere separando, exemplo: dd/mm/aaaa

```
>>> nasc = "20/05/1997"
>>> nasc.split('/')
['20', '05', '1997']
```